# Where to index correctly in MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm having a few queries similar to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE cat = X 
AND cat2 = X 
AND title LIKE %X% 
AND content LIKE %X% 
AND email LIKE %X% 
AND box LIKE %X% 
AND address LIKE %X%
```

Those long and slightly malformed queries are done by a proprietary software, so I can't optimize them. Any ideas where I should index and improve to get better performance?

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that **does not start** with a wildcard character.

So you are out of luck for the `LIKE %X%` parts. For those, no index can be used and MySQL has to do a full scan of the table.

Comment: @Karolis What is not the case?

Comment: What can i do to improve %X% likes? :(

Comment: You can't do anything, the entire table has to be scanned for that operation.

Comment: @Karolis, this answer is 100% correct and applicable to the question. Please explain your comment.

Comment: @Pelle The answer is updated. When I wrote the comment there was no last sentence. So the context was a little different.

Comment: @Karolis I only added the last sentence. All before that was the same.

Comment: @cularis Yes I know, but the last sentence changes the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: What alternative would be than using LIKEs? So i can recommend to the software authors.

Comment: Well, there is the full-text index on MyISAM but thats a double-edged sword. One thing to consider would be using `LIKE X%` so that an index can be used on the like.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing is only useful if the expression tells you something about the **beginning** of a value. So, the LIKE operator only is useful when the expression does not start with a wildcard.

```
field1 =    'value'   # Index this
field2 LIKE 'value%'  # Index this
field3 LIKE '%value%' # Do not index, beginning characters unknown.
field4 LIKE '%value%' # Do not index, beginning characters unknown.
```

Also for the `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` operators, indexing the fields can be useful.

In your situation, put an index on `cat` and `cat2`.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get anywhere with the `LIKE` parts of that query. But you can make sure that `cat` and `cat2` are quick, by providing a **combined** index for those 2 columns.

Comment: While cularis answer is correct it doesn't offer the best possible solution. So +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have a multi-column index on cat and cat2:

```
INDEX( cat, cat2 )
```

index on your string columns will not help at all as cularis mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If many of the consecutive queries are exactly the same (I do not know if this is the case), you would greatly benefit from [MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html).